# Bash - exit does not exit script (only subshell)

Tags: bash, function, exit, subshell, jo

The topic proposed from the moderator does not answer this question.

The `exit` command in the following script is supposed to exit the entire script. 
Which normally happens if you put an `exit` command into a function. 
But not in this case:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash


function embedded()
{
  exit 1
  ls | head -1
}

jo name="$(embedded)" \
   age=50

printf "\nThe script is still alive.\n"
```

Output:

```
{"name":null,"age":50}

The script is still alive.
```

It continues to execute the rest of the script. 
Does someone know why this happens? 
Is there something inside the `jo` program that prevents the `exit`?

Comment: That's what a subshell _does,_ you can't make the parent shell exit, or otherwise modify its state, without its cooperation. A common arrangement would be `value=$(function) || exit; jo name="$value"` etc

Comment: @That is not true. Usually an `exit` inside a functions exits the entire script.

Comment: You are missing the point. The command substitution `$(...)` creates a new shell instance; the function exits that alright, but the parent shell is unaffected.

Comment: @tripleee Ok, I think that last comment was the missing piece of information I needed. That was the part I did not understand. Thanks.